# I am trying to insert int values into string and instead of 1 i get 10

Tags: c++, nodes, adjacency-list

I got 1005 nodes so i enter 1005 here
and values 1 to 1005 through the loop 
ps. even if i enter manually i get the same print

```
void call() 
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter Number of characters";       string s;
    cin >> t;
    cout << "Enter char names :";
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) 
    {
        x = i + 1;
        str1 = to_string(x);
        //cin >> str1;
        insertd(str1);
    }
}


void insertd(string n) {
    node *ptr = new node;

    ptr->name = n;

    if (head == NULL) {

        head = ptr;

        last = ptr;

    }

    else {

        last->down = ptr;

        last = ptr;

    }

}
```

and when i print using this part here

```
void print() {
    current = head;
    node *p;
    while (current != NULL) {
        p = current;
        while (p != NULL) {
            cout << p->name << p->weight << "   ";
            p = p->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
        current = current->down;
    }
}
```

i get result like 10,20,30 instead of 1 ,2,3

Comment: Is p->weight maybe 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not print 10 instead of 0 if you are using std::to_string for the conversion.
Can you try printing the name only?

```
std::cout << p->name << std::endl
```

> You are certainly having 0 for p->weight.